# Please i dont know where i get it wrong

Tags: javascript, function, fetch-api

```
const quoteText = document.querySelector("quote")
quoteBtn = document.querySelector("button")

// random quote function
function randomQuote() {

    //Fetching random quote from API and parsing it into Js Object
    fetch("https://api.quotable.io/random").then(res => res.json()).then(result=>{
        console.log(result);
        quoteText.innerText = result.content;
    }); 
    
}

quoteBtn.addEventListener("click", randomQuote);
```

I expect it to next the quote as i am clicking on it, but rather it is displaying in the console as "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')"

Comment: There's no `<quote>` element in your markup at the time the script is run.

Comment: error msg is pretty clear. `quoteText` is null

Comment: Please go read [ask], and [mre]. The former already has some hints for you on the very first thing you got "wrong" here - the question title.

Comment: You have to use a `.` or  `#` in document.querySelector("quote"). Like `document.querySelector(". quote")`

Comment: The error message is clear - `quoteText` does not contain the reference to any element, but only `null`. So your question is most likely to be considered a duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: To my best understanding, i have tried everything i knew it is not working, yet all provided solutions by bosses here is not working too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `document.querySelector()`, you need to use a class or an id, unless your target is a native html element. `<quote>` is not a native html element. So I guess you need to use:

```
const quoteText = document.querySelector(".quote")
```

Mind the `.` in `document.querySelector(".quote")`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to fetch a random quote from an API and display it on a website when a button is clicked.

There's a syntax error in the code, the quoteBtn declaration is missing a var or const keyword, which should be fixed:

```
const quoteText = document.querySelector("quote");
const quoteBtn = document.querySelector("button");
```

Additionally, make sure that the elements with the quote and button class names actually exist in your HTML, otherwise `quoteText` and `quoteBtn` will be null and the code will throw an error when trying to add the click event listener.